# url encoding c# mismatch encoding

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a large url that I am encoding using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode. When I encode it its not encoding it like the working example I have. I am not sure what the problem is, maybe different character type or something, I put an example of what suppose to be created and what actually being created. thanks for any help, i am lost on this one.

Working exmaple (look how this one has Did%252Citag%252 and the other doesnt)

22%7Chttp%3A%2F%2Fv17.nonxt1.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fid%3D0b608733ae5257c3%26itag%3D22%26source%3Dpicasa%26ip%3D0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3D0%26expire%3D1333533157%26sparams%3Did%252Citag%252Csource%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Cexpire%26signature%3D8AD67D74F34FBAFBBA87616C0AED4A336DF0982A.129E2B5E648F8A2F35A34F312AC5C3C957A1C40A%26key%3Dlh1%2C35%7Chttp%3A%2F%2Fv18.nonxt3.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fid%3D0b608733ae5257c3%26itag%3D35%26source%3Dpicasa%26ip%3D0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3D0%26expire%3D1333533157%26sparams%3Did%252Citag%252Csource%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Cexpire%26signature%3D7A58A11994C710872E945D0EAA6E43B6BFB8A648.B9C1D9FB377E1A49EBF3DC6C166C0B6E3E94EC24%26key%3Dlh1%2C34%7Chttp%3A%2F%2Fv6.nonxt1.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fid%3D0b608733ae5257c3%26itag%3D34%26source%3Dpicasa%26ip%3D0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3D0%26expire%3D1333533157%26sparams%3Did%252Citag%252Csource%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Cexpire%26signature%3D260B10850A3448C849B8B8F1F2AF5E31244E71BC.6D7420FD66B85D40982BFB2C847EDB46021C63AE%26key%3Dlh1%2C5%7Chttp%3A%2F%2Fv23.nonxt7.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fid%3D0b608733ae5257c3%26itag%3D5%26source%3Dpicasa%26ip%3D0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3D0%26expire%3D1333533157%26sparams%3Did%252Citag%252Csource%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Cexpire%26signature%3D9894DCDA7D2634EE0006CE0F6E0E29ABF7A8F253.18765D7CD7BDE80ED1A47DC8EC559C3E05C92F56%26key%3Dlh1

Here is an example of the one I am creating (see this one encodes as did%2citag%2)

5%7chttp%3a%2f%2fv23.nonxt7.googlevideo.com%2fvideoplayback%3fid%3d0b608733ae5257c3%26itag%3d5%26source%3dpicasa%26ip%3d0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3d0%26expire%3d1333562840%26sparams%3did%2citag%2csource%2cip%2cipbits%2cexpire%26signature%3dC0E2993011931D9F5FCAFAF54E821415F6042DDD.477CD23B021563A6DE30E858E35C21046E0B0BA6%26key%3dlh1%2c18%7chttp%3a%2f%2fv11.nonxt4.googlevideo.com%2fvideoplayback%3fid%3d0b608733ae5257c3%26itag%3d18%26source%3dpicasa%26ip%3d0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3d0%26expire%3d1333562840%26sparams%3did%2citag%2csource%2cip%2cipbits%2cexpire%26signature%3d696501A8ACBA0E1246173B040E0FB81DA8EBCDC7.944BA6C08C630EFFC2456D66BAD12376D7E377B2%26key%3dlh1%2c34%7chttp%3a%2f%2fv6.nonxt1.googlevideo.com%2fvideoplayback%3fid%3d0b608733ae5257c3%26itag%3d34%26source%3dpicasa%26ip%3d0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3d0%26expire%3d1333562840%26sparams%3did%2citag%2csource%2cip%2cipbits%2cexpire%26signature%3dDDD3D9081F7F2FF462D17CFAE6CAB72AEB86DEA9.3275E0EE8921EF728132035FC94BEF5926A0B7C1%26key%3dlh1%2c35%7chttp%3a%2f%2fv18.nonxt3.googlevideo.com%2fvideoplayback%3fid%3d0b608733ae5257c3%26itag%3d35%26source%3dpicasa%26ip%3d0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3d0%26expire%3d1333562840%26sparams%3did%2citag%2csource%2cip%2cipbits%2cexpire%26signature%3d7826E7470450F9F473BC7A845967EF3AC655CFB.3850F952F5D68151D325CD754C581CD66B0BC4D7%26key%3dlh1%2c22%7chttp%3a%2f%2fv17.nonxt1.googlevideo.com%2fvideoplayback%3fid%3d0b608733ae5257c3%26itag%3d22%26source%3dpicasa%26ip%3d0.0.0.0%26ipbits%3d0%26expire%3d1333562840%26sparams%3did%2citag%2csource%2cip%2cipbits%2cexpire%26signature%3d32FAAE6AE74B22BFB3DBD4300CEEDBC1A12A9ED4.8014678ABB1AEE93FB4B1C36E2C74C89102DC112%26key%3dlh1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like in the first example the URL is double encoded. Meaning if you look at decoded sparams parameter it is represented as

> sparams=id%2Citag%2Csource%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire

In your second example

> sparams=id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire

So, what is happening in the first example is that, they are doing a UrlEncode on the value first. Using this value Construct the URL and then do UrlEncode on the constructed URL.

**UPDATE :** This is a general practice to be followed if the value of your querystring contains values which needs to be UrlEncoded (eg. , & space ? etc)

Comment: Ok, thanks i see whats going on now. Is there a way in c# to break down a url. Encode the part that I want, and then join the url back together, and then encode?

Comment: How are your constructing your Url? When you are assigning the value you can encode once. After the construction of the URL you can encode once. To be effective this needs to be done when you are building the URL and on an already exisiting Url.

Comment: The url are appending to a stringbuilder object. So I have access to each url.

Comment: Before appending the value to the string builder do a HtmlEncode. Once the URL is fully constructed do another encode. eg stringBuilder.Append("&sparam=").Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sparamValues); string finalUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(stringBuilder.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

According to [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) standards, your example is fine. There is no %252 symbol.

Comment: Then why does the working example works and my exampl(which does not have that does not work) how is that %252 being created

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are expecting, but when you fire these strings into a [URL Decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/), this is what you get:

**String 1**

```
22|http://v17.nonxt1.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=0b608733ae5257c3&itag=22&source=picasa&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1333533157&sparams=id%2Citag%2Csource%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire&signature=8AD67D74F34FBAFBBA87616C0AED4A336DF0982A.129E2B5E648F8A2F35A34F312AC5C3C957A1C40A&key=lh1,35|http://v18.nonxt3.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=0b608733ae5257c3&itag=35&source=picasa&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1333533157&sparams=id%2Citag%2Csource%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire&signature=7A58A11994C710872E945D0EAA6E43B6BFB8A648.B9C1D9FB377E1A49EBF3DC6C166C0B6E3E94EC24&key=lh1,34|http://v6.nonxt1.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=0b608733ae5257c3&itag=34&source=picasa&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1333533157&sparams=id%2Citag%2Csource%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire&signature=260B10850A3448C849B8B8F1F2AF5E31244E71BC.6D7420FD66B85D40982BFB2C847EDB46021C63AE&key=lh1,5|http://v23.nonxt7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=0b608733ae5257c3&itag=5&source=picasa&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1333533157&sparams=id%2Citag%2Csource%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire&signature=9894DCDA7D2634EE0006CE0F6E0E29ABF7A8F253.18765D7CD7BDE80ED1A47DC8EC559C3E05C92F56&key=lh1
```

**String 2**

```
5|http://v23.nonxt7.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=0b608733ae5257c3&itag=5&source=picasa&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1333562840&sparams=id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=C0E2993011931D9F5FCAFAF54E821415F6042DDD.477CD23B021563A6DE30E858E35C21046E0B0BA6&key=lh1,18|http://v11.nonxt4.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=0b608733ae5257c3&itag=18&source=picasa&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1333562840&sparams=id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=696501A8ACBA0E1246173B040E0FB81DA8EBCDC7.944BA6C08C630EFFC2456D66BAD12376D7E377B2&key=lh1,34|http://v6.nonxt1.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=0b608733ae5257c3&itag=34&source=picasa&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1333562840&sparams=id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=DDD3D9081F7F2FF462D17CFAE6CAB72AEB86DEA9.3275E0EE8921EF728132035FC94BEF5926A0B7C1&key=lh1,35|http://v18.nonxt3.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=0b608733ae5257c3&itag=35&source=picasa&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1333562840&sparams=id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=7826E7470450F9F473BC7A845967EF3AC655CFB.3850F952F5D68151D325CD754C581CD66B0BC4D7&key=lh1,22|http://v17.nonxt1.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?id=0b608733ae5257c3&itag=22&source=picasa&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1333562840&sparams=id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=32FAAE6AE74B22BFB3DBD4300CEEDBC1A12A9ED4.8014678ABB1AEE93FB4B1C36E2C74C89102DC112&key=lh1
```

You URLS are quite different, and they also have a leading chars that I'm not sure you are wanting.

Comment: I do want them if it works lol. So it looks like before I encode it i have to replace characters with encoded characters. Seems odd.